# VFS: Cannot open root device "" or 03:02 when booting Damn Small Linux over PXE

Tags: pxe, knoppix, dsl

I'm trying to set up a PXE boot server for multiple different OSes. So far I have it working with Linux Mint, Arch Linux, and a GParted image. I'm trying to do Damn Small Linux completely within RAM, so the host doesn't have to stay connected to the network to work. I followed this tutorial: http://damnsmalllinux.org/f/topic-3-26-15960-0.html

However, I get the following screen when I try to boot it:

```
vesafb: scrolling: redraw
vesafb: directcolor: size=0:8:8:8, shift=0:16:8:0
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x37
fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
pty: 256 Unix98 ptys configured
FDC 0 is a S82078B
RAMDISK driver initialized: 16 RAM disks of 100000K size 1024 blocksize
Uniform Multi-Platform E-IDE driver Revision: 7.00beta4-2.4
ide: Assuming 33MHz system bus speed for PIO modes; override with idebus=xx
PIIX3: IDE controller at PCI slot 00:01.1
PIIX3: chipset revision 0
PIIX3: not 100% native mode: will probe irqs later
    ide0: BM-DMA at 0xc300-0xc307, BIOS settings: hda:pio, hdb:pio
    ide1: BM-DMA at 0xc308-0xc30f, BIOS settings: hdc:pio, hdd:pio
ide: late registration of driver.
SCSI subsystem driver Revision: 1.00
kmod: failed to exec /sbin/modprobe -s -k scsi_hostadapter, errno = 2
kmod: failed to exec /sbin/modprobe -s -k scsi_hostadapter, errno = 2
Initializing Cryptographic API
NET4: Linux TCP/IP 1.0 for NET4.0
IP Protocols: ICMP, UDP, TCP, IGMP
IP: routing cache hash table of 4096 buckets, 32Kbytes
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 32768 bind 32768)
NET4: Unix domain sockets 1.0/SMP for Linux NET4.0.
RAMDISK: Compressed image found at block 0
Freeing initrd memory: 49583k freed
VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem).
kmod: failed to exec /sbin/modprobe -s -k block-major-3, errno = 2
VFS: Cannot open root device "" or 03:02
Please append a correct "root=" boot option
Kernel panic: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on 03:02
```

I'm not sure what I need to do here. My minirt24.gz is available for inspection at https://k7dxs.xyz/files/minirt24.gz, and here is the relevant portion of my `pxelinux.cfg/default`:

```
LABEL Damn Small Linux
    LINUX dsl/linux24
    APPEND ramdisk_size=100000 init=/etc/init lang=us apm=power-off vga=789 initrd=dsl/minirt24.gz nomce noapic loud BOOT_IMAGE=knoppix frominitrd nopcmcia noagp noswap base
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/).  I've copied the contents for you.  The `kmod: failed to exec …` lines seem relevant, as well as the final three.

Comment: @Fox Thank you for doing that for me. The reason I did not originally was because of [this post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4094/78518) on that meta question. I'm curious, did you type it yourself or use some program to transcribe it?

Comment: I admit that I'm very biased toward text, as a frequent Lynx user.  I actually transcribed images from four different posts last night, and hand-typed all of them.  I should probably find some OCR software if I plan to keep doing that

Comment: Alright, well thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that at [ibiblio](http://distro.ibiblio.org/damnsmall/current/) they offer an iso built for this, with the initrd pre-packed with the image. It is labeled `dsl-x.y.zz-initrd.iso` where x.y.zz is the version number. Unfortunately this is not documented in the readme offered in the same directory, but it works.